# Question about two vehicles moving toward each other, but the answer doesn't seem correct, am I missing a key concept?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

**The problem statement**

Vehicle A and Vehicle B are moving in opposite directions on the NJTP. Vehicle A is heading south toward atlantic city while vehicle B is heading north towards Hoboken. In situation 1 and 2 described below, at t = 0s both vehicles are at a distance of separation of 400m and are moving towards each other.

Situation 1:    When vehicle A is moving at a constant velocity of 30 m/s and travels a distance of 120 m, the vehicles pass each other on the turnpike.

Situation 2:    When vehicle A is moving at a constant velocity of 80 m/s and after a time of 3s, the vehicles pass each other on the turnpike.

For vehicle A label variables as:   Via, Vfa, aa, da,ta
For vehicle B label variables as:   Vib, Vfb, ab,db, tb

In the ORDER INDICATED:

(a) Calculate the initial velocity of vehicle B or Vib; and

(b) Then calculate the acceleration of vehicle B or ab

Show all work in DETAIL and keep all numerical values to the nearest hundredth value. Draw and label all pictures

Note:   You will receive NO CREDIT if you first calculate part (b) and then part (a)

For situations 1 and 2

vib = constant   ; vfb ≠ a constant value since its value changes w/ time

ab = constant

**My Work**

Situation 1:
Da + Db = 400

Via = 30 m/s
Vfa = 30 m/s
a = 0 m/s2
da = 120 m
ta = ?

Vave = d/ t = vf + vi /2
Vave = da/ta
ta = 4s

db = 280
ta = 4s

Situation 2:
Via = 80 m/s
aa = 0 m/s2
vfa = 80 m/s
ta = 3s = tb
da = ?

Using same equation as in situation 2,

da = 240

db=160
tb = 3s

Situation 1
db = vibtb + 1/2abtb^2
280 = vib(4) + 1/2 (ab)(4)^2

Situation 2
db = vibtb + 1/2abtb2
160 = vib(3) + 1/2 (ab)(3)^2

Solving for ab I get ab = 11.85 / vib

Plugging that back into the equation I get Vib = .34 m/s and plugging that into the 280 = (.34)(4) + 1/2 (ab)(4)^2 = ab = 34.82 m/s^2.

I'm sorry if I'm new and breaking the rules, but this problem has really been bothering me for the last week.  My friend says it's correct, but it just seems too low of an initial  velocity.

Comment: Please consider using LaTeX to typeset your formulae, they are neither pleasing to the eye nor easy to read if you don't. The Stack Exchange software automatically interprets stuff between dollar signs are LaTeX in MathMode. A quick tutorial is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1)

Comment: Are you supposed to use both situations A and B together to get the two answers?

Comment: Hi user52027, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Questions where you're just asking for someone to check your work are off topic here, according to our homework policy (linked in the post notice above). So now you know for next time. :-) If you're confused about some specific concept, feel free to edit your question to ask about that and it can be taken off hold.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough information to do the problem.  In situation 1, they meet at $t=4 s$ and B has covered $280 m$.  It could be that B traveled $70 m/s$ the whole time and the acceleration is zero.  It could be that B started at rest and accelerated uniformly.  Then $280=\frac 12a(4^2)$ or $a=35m/s^2$  Actually you are told B is moving, so it can't start at rest, but it could start very slowly.  There is a continuum of solutions, plus the acceleration of B could even be changing.

Comment: I'm confused, now I may be wrong, but doesn't the problem state that vib = constant ; vfb ≠ a constant value since its value changes w/ time

ab = constant

Comment: Ok, I see that the acceleration is constant, but you still can't tell what it is.  I thought that was part of your work.  You could have something close to the two solutions I gave above (not quite as you are told there is some initial velocity and some acceleration) or many more.  For situation 2, you know A traveled 240 m in 3 sec, so B traveled 160 m in 3 sec.

Comment: Okay, so just to be sure that I understand you correctly, it COULD be those values but it could could also be other values that correspond?  I'm sorry for my questions but I'm in a 6 week Physics I class so we can't really cover everything in as much detail as I like to when I learn something.

Comment: Yes, you could start at, say $20 m/sec$ and accelerate.  You have $db=v_{ib}t+\frac 12at^2$  We are given that $s=280, t=4$, but we still have one equation and two unknowns.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now.  Thank you for your help.  I needed these problem for those 6 bonus points on our grade :)